# Can't post value to codeigniter controller with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So i want to do an update function by using ajax. i have two parameters and i want to pass the parameters to my CI controller. but i got an error, and i thought it was the parameter that didn't get pass to the controller.

here is my ajax function:

```
function suspend(tipe, id){
    var postData = {
        'tipe' : tipe,
        'id' : id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=site_url("amas/c_agency/suspend_agency/");?>",
        data: postData,
        success: function(data){
            if(tipe == 0){
                $("#suspend").attr("onclick","suspend(1,"+id+")");
            }else{
                $("#suspend").attr("onclick","suspend(0,"+id+")");
            }
            alertify.success("Agency berhasil disuspend!");
        } ,
        error: function() {
            alertify.error("Gagal suspend agency!");
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my codeigniter controller:

```
function suspend_agency(){
        $session['hasil'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $login_id = $session['hasil']->login_id;

        $tipe = $this->input->post('tipe');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        if($tipe == 0){
            $id = array(
                'id_agency' => $id
            );
            $data = array(
                'is_suspend' => '1',
                'suspend_by' => $login_id,
                'suspend_at' => date("Y-m-d")
            );
        }else{
            $id = array(
                'id_agency' => $id
            );
            $data = array(
                'is_suspend' => '0'
            );
        }

        $result = $this->m_agency->suspend_agency($id, $data);
    }
```

i have tried to change ajax data to data: `"tipe="+tipe+"&id="+id` bu it didn't work either.

Comment: Please check your Console if the values are being passed in your AJAX Request.

Comment: yes, the value are being passed into my ajax request, but i think the value are not passed into the controller

Comment: just use `print_r($_POST); die;` at the top of your `suspend_agency` method to check if the values are being passed to controller

Comment: and how can i even check the `print_r`value?

Comment: in the Network Tab for each AJAX Call there is a Response Tab.

Comment: try to change `site_url` to `base_url`. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Also, check the URL in ajax pointing to the correct path to the controller and method.

Comment: Just write ```echo '<pre>'; var_dump($this->input->post()); die();``` in the first line line of the method named **suspend_agency** and then tell me what does it show.

Comment: Where you send back your data to browser? Post what you have in m_agency.

Comment: "*but i got an error*", please specify which error. Also check if your url is correct, you use `ama/c_agency/function` in another question of yours and not `amas/...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print your variable. `echo json_encode($result);`

```
function suspend_agency(){
    $session['hasil'] = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $login_id = $session['hasil']->login_id;

    $tipe = $this->input->post('tipe');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    if($tipe == 0){
        $id = array(
            'id_agency' => $id
        );
        $data = array(
            'is_suspend' => '1',
            'suspend_by' => $login_id,
            'suspend_at' => date("Y-m-d")
        );
    }else{
        $id = array(
            'id_agency' => $id
        );
        $data = array(
            'is_suspend' => '0'
        );
    }

    $result = $this->m_agency->suspend_agency($id, $data);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: OP says that they get an error (not sure what yet) but adding an `echo` is unlikely to change that

Comment: the problem is not getting a value back from the controller, it's to get the value to the controller

Comment: printing the variable will show you what error you have to correct and also for your ajax wait for the response data

Comment: I also copied your code and did the test and in the controller you get the data sent by post

Comment: and also delete **amas/** `<? = site_url ("amas / c_agency / suspend_agency /");?>` and put this `<? = site_url ("c_agency / suspend_agency /");?>` because I suppose **c_agency** is your controller and **suspend_agency** is your method